# Which class was written first in Python: type or object?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, metaprogramming, metaclass

All classes are subclasses of the *object* and at the same time they all are instances of the *type*. Therefore, the *object* is an instance of the *type*, and the *type* is an subclass of the *object*. But, obviously, one of these connections is fictitious. Which class in the implementation of python is written first?

Comment: Perhaps you should check their git history? :)

Comment: Why do you assume there is a "first"? When you have two modules, which each import things from each other, which has the declarations that are "first"?

Comment: If you're looking for a historical view, remember that before Python... 2.6? there were "old-style classes" and "new-style classes"; in that sense `class` was a thing before `type` and `object`.

Comment: Secondly, there's no such thing as "the implementation of python" – there are several. Are you talking about CPython? Which version of CPython?

Comment: You've correctly observed a paradox. There is no answer to which is first. The paradox is implemented deep in the language. Neither of these is implemented in Python as a class and there is no way to implement something like that in your own classes.

Comment: [This comment in a CPython commit from 2001](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/6d6c1a35e08b95a83dbe47dbd9e6474daff00354/Objects/typeobject.c#L832) implies `object` is the base type of all objects, but go figure.

Comment: How can two things refer to each other? The second thing must exist when the first is created so that the first can refer to the second.

Comment: Ok, let's talk about CPython, for example.

Comment: @ИльяЦелковой The interpreter internals would be perfectly allowed to internally "sneak in" a circular reference after the two are created.

Comment: @ИльяЦелковой Talking about `CPython`, everything is a `PyObject`, therefore an `object` and I would say that `object` just _pretends_ to be an instance of `type`, but it pretends it so well that this implementation detail is not relevant outside of `CPython`.

Comment: @zvone Someone is definitely pretends. But the source code of CPython is so large and complicated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Both were written at the same time, when the "new style classes" were created, during the development cycle that ended up in Python 2.2. The development of that version made explicit and formalized the metaclass mechanism, and `object` and `type` are bound from their inception.

While it is impossible for one, in plain (or even arcane) Python code to create a class that is both a supertype of your class and an instance of it, as `object` is to `type`, when coding the classes in lower level, in the case of cPython, in the C source code of the language, that is perfectly possible: both are statically declared, and the plain forward reference used by the C pre-processor is enough to be able to refer to `object` in `type`'s slots before `object`'s code is declared and vice versa.

You may want to read some posts from the time the new style classes where created, and this is a good starting point: https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2.3/descrintro/